# 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.GraphicCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange'

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, esri

I have the following code that is the addrange method:

```
foreach (var graphic in buffersList)
{
    if (!graphicsLayerHeat.Graphics.Contains(graphic))
    {
       graphicsLayerHeat.Graphics.AddRange(buffersList);  
    }
}
```

But the visual studio prompts me this error

> 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.GraphicCollection' does not contain a definition
>   for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.GraphicCollection' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I change the method so that it can work the same way without using addrange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
graphicsLayerHeat.Graphics.AddRange(buffersList);
```

to this:

```
graphicsLayerHeat.Graphics.Add(graphic);
```

I assume you don't want to add the `bufferlist` over and over again (as the other answerer's solution would do).

The newer version of the ESRI silverlight API does have an `AddRange` method (time to update?), but I don't think that's what you want to use since you also want to do the contains check.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `foreach` loop to add the items manually

```
foreach (var buffer in buffersList) {
 graphicsLayerHeat.Graphics.Add(buffer);
}
```

If this is a common operation you may just want to create an `AddRange` extension method yourself

```
static void AddRange(this GraphicsCollection source, GraphicsCollection list) {
  foreach (var item it list) { 
    source.Add(item);
  }
}
```

It's possible this could be made more general but I'm unfamiliar with the `GraphicsCollection` type so I don't know what interfaces it implements